# Parsing LatLong from EXIF using Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, exif, flutterflow

Does anyone have an example of how to parse the GPS coordinates. I'm assuming it would return LatLng from the exif tags in Flutter? I'm embedding it in FlutterFlow as a custom action so I can capture where an image was taken when it is uploaded into my app.

Here is the code template I'm starting with. As I make progress I'll update it.

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

Future<LatLng> parseGPSfromEXIF(String url) async {
  // Add your function code here!
}
```